# Unable to build 32bit library on Centos7

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, centos, centos7

I have Centos7 Vagrant box which has 'devtoolset-7'.

I use 'CMake' to build and compile my library. Here is the CMakeLists.txt file

```
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)
include_directories("../Include" "/usr/include/libusb-1.0")
add_library(CXIOInterface SHARED 
        CXIOInterface.cpp
        HidInterface_Linux.cpp
        HidDevice_Linux.cpp
        ../Include/Debug.cpp
        app.cpp
        CrcLibrary.cpp
        ContextFunctions.cpp)
set(PROJECT_LINK_LIBS -ludev -lusb-1.0)
target_link_libraries(CXIOInterface LINK_PUBLIC ${PROJECT_LINK_LIBS})
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-m32")
```

Everything works fine when I compile it for 64-bit. But when I compile it for 32-bit, I get error saying:

```
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/7/ld: skipping incompatible /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/7/libstdc++_nonshared.a when searching for -lstdc++_nonshared
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/7/ld: cannot find -lstdc++_nonshared
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CXIOInterface/libCXIOInterface.so] Error 1
```

Can you guys please help me, I am unable to understand what to do here.

There is already a link which tells me to install rpm, but I am a ubuntu user not Centos. Using it for the first time.

https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=64011

Comment: You need an older devtoolset. Try compiling with the default g++ 5.x inside Centos (scl disable devtoolset). You can install rpm packages with yum anyway.

Comment: I said source scl_source disable devtoolset-7 and run the make command, it gave the same error

Comment: could you show the output of `yum repolist` and `rpm -qa | grep devtoolset`

Answer (score 0):

> /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/7/ld: skipping incompatible /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/7/libstdc++_nonshared.a when searching for -lstdc++_nonshared

Means that the library the the linker finds is no compatible with the ABI, in this case, it is not 32-bit compatible.

This happens because you are missing a package required for this, just like the link you added states.

First, find out the current version of devtoolset you have installed:

```
rpm -qa | grep devtoolset-7
```

From the output, you should be able to easily figure out what version you are using right now.

Then, try running:

```
yum install devtoolset-7-libstdc++-devel-7.2.1-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

**Note**: I used 7.2.1-1 because this was the one I found when searching this in Google, if you installed a different version, use it instead.

Comment: I got the following error: No package devtoolset-7-libstdc++-devel-7.2.1-1.el7.x86_64.rpm available.

Comment: How to find out what version should I install